# SQL function for implementing count

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2005, and want a user defined function to implement the following:

Parameter: @SQL varchar(max)

```
execute 'select count(1) from (' + @sql + ')'
```

and return the result as integer.

This is the dummy code >>

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].udf_GetCountFromSQL ( @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS INT
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @returnValue INT
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (' + @SQL + ')'
        EXEC @returnValue= @SQL

        RETURN @returnValue ;
    END
```

`@SQL` here is dynamic sql, not stored procedure name, so it doesn't work.

Wait to be helped out, thanks in advance.

Elaine

Comment: @Pavanred, is come up with the function that can get the count(..) , I'm looking at http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=SQL_2005_-_Why_You_Can%27t_EXEC%28%29_Inside_a_UDF, looks like it's impossible to use dynamical sql inside a UDF.

Comment: Why COUNT(1) instead of COUNT(*) ?

Comment: @iDevlop both works, doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't execute dynamic SQL in a user defined function.
You'd need to change it to a stored procedure and use sp_executesql to get the count into a variable - you can then pass the count out as an OUTPUT parameter (or RETURN value if you want).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExampleSproc(@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @RowCount INTEGER OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(1) FROM (' + @SQL + ') x'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@RowCount INTEGER OUT', @RowCount OUT
END
```

Then call like this:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INTEGER
EXECUTE dbo.ExampleSproc '...Some SQL...', @RowCount OUTPUT
```

However, you need to be very careful as you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks (what if @SQL contains something dodgy?).

Comment: error when do select dbo.ExampleSproc ('select 1') - info >> Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function. " -- i think here's the answer -- http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=SQL_2005_-_Why_You_Can%27t_EXEC%28%29_Inside_a_UDF  seems impossible to exec dynamic sql in udf?

Comment: @elaine Yes, that's what I said above ;)

Comment: even using this way, I cannot meet the requirement. :) but thanks, I found an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, why don't you just

```
select @@rowcount
```

after executing the query?

Comment: because it will always be 1 for a query like `select count(*) from YourTable` because there is only one row returned with the count of the entire table.

Comment: uuh ... ok, let me rephrase. Since the OP seems to want to exec an arbitrary SQL statement on a connection with the primary purpose in order to determine the rowcount from said query, why not consider @@rowcounting after executing the arbitrary statement on the same connection as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To call dynamic SQL you have to use parantheses around the parameter:

```
EXEC (@SQL)
```

But you can't use a statement with side effects inside a UDF, so its impossible to execute dynamic SQL.

Besides this, its not possible to return a value from your dynamic SQL query and store it in a variable.

Comment: It is possible to execute dynamic sql and get the value into a variable, you just have to use sp_executesql per my answer. Obv not within a UDF